# Minimal number of features and observations for random forest regression analysis?

Tags: random-forest, sample-size, nonlinear-regression, assumptions

Linear regression is a suitable regression method even for small numbers of observations as long as there are enough observations per predictor (with factors 5 to 15 given as rules of thumb) and we have certain ideas of how the predictors "work" (linear or curved fashion, interactions etc.).

Random forests promise to work out of the box with no assumptions about linearity or interactions etc. whilst still provide guard over overfitting. Software packages such as `ranger` promise p-values for inference on variable importance. I am therefore inclined to expand my knowledge on Random Forest.

However, in comments on CrossValidated I seem to often find opinions, that a specific sample size within the specific question is to small to use random forests sensibly.

I work in medicine, often with sample sizes of 30 or 150 or 500, rarely over 1000. Do random forests make sense in that range? Are there sensibe rules of thumb on what samples sizes are suitable for random forest analysis (be it prediction or inference)? I am obviously aware, that that will depend on the individual circumstances case-by-case but rules such as "have at least 10 observations per predictor in OLS linear regression" are still usefull, even if not "true" for special circumstances.

Comment: Might also be useful to know how many predictors you typically have (and what mix of continuous/categorical (and how many levels)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Too long for a comment sorry)

There are great references on the matter. Of the top of my head I can think: van der Ploeg et al. (2014) *[Modern modelling techniques are data hungry: a simulation study for predicting dichotomous endpoints](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137)*  and Riley et al. (2019)'s *[Minimum sample size for developing a multivariable prediction model: Part I–Continuous outcomes](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.7993)* & *[Minimum sample size for developing a multivariable prediction model: PART II - binary and time-to-event outcomes](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.7992)*. I also liked Riley et al. (2021) *[Minimum sample size for external validation of a clinical prediction model with a binary outcome](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.9025)* but doesn't cover that much more ground than the two 2019 papers. As a rule of thumb, the fewer assumptions a technique makes, the more data-hungry has to be. I would therefore strongly urge you to do a small simulation study based on your sample size and individual application to ensure you get reasonable convergence as well as investigate the shape of the model's [learning curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve_(machine_learning)).

Comment: I guess: Do a simuation study and watch the learning curves is probably the most to the point answer here and worth the bounty. Just in case not every other reader reads the links: The first states concludes that "up to ten times as many events per variable" and that for medical prediction "only very large datasets" should be used.

Comment: The second ilink is behind a paywall and does not contain the word random forest. I definitely need to read the last one at a later point in time. It obviously aims at calibration of prediction studies and external validation and seems to be very worthwhile.

Comment: So the next step for me will be to find good information so I do not have to reinvent the wheel for simulation studies.

Comment: 0. Thanks. Agreed. As mentioned, this is mostly an extended comment. 1. You can find all the papers for free if you look them up in Google Scholar. I put in the official link to the publications. 2. I linked them cause they show how the investigation could be done for your particular case (continuous or binary outcomes). The fourth one shows how the simulation settings vary (for C-statistic, calibration slope, etc.) The actual learning algorithm (RF, GBM, NN) shouldn't affect how the investigation is set.